# Est-ce que "donnée" est correct au singulier ?

Tags: accord, pluriel

Je connais des gens qui utilisent parfois le mot "*donnée*" au singulier, dans le sens de "*données informatique*".

J'ai toujours trouvé ça bizarre, pour moi ça n'a pas de sens (à partir de quand il y en a "plusieurs" ?) et je ne pense que ce n'est pas correct, mais je ne trouve aucune information dans les différents dictionnaires en ligne sur l'utilisation du singulier dans ce sens.

Tout les emplois que je connais sont au pluriel (*base de données*, *traitement de données*, *données personnelles*, ...), et je ne crois pas avoir croisé le singulier autrement qu'à l'oral.

Je ne saisis pas moi-même totalement quand les gens utilisent "***une*** *donnée*" plutôt que "***des*** *données*" donc c'est une supposition, mais si j'ai bien compris ça peut s'appliquer à des tableaux, des fichiers texte, des chaînes de caractère, et autres choses qui contiennent *des* données mais qui sont relativement **dénombrables**.

Étrangement, ce qui pourrait correspondre au terme "*une donnée*" est rarement appelé comme ça. Si par exemple on appelle "*données utilisateur*" l'ensemble nom, prénom et adresse mail, on va plutôt parler de "*champ*", d'"*attribut*", de "*paramètre*", voire de "*colonne*" (dans le contexte d'une base de données) pour un élément précis de cet ensemble.

J'ai entendu des choses comme :

> La donnée en entrée [...]
>
> Je récupère ma donnée, je la traite et je la renvoie.

Les dictionnaires ne mentionnent pas grand-chose à ce sujet, le problème étant que me singulier existe et a un sens pour les autres signification, comme en mathématiques (ou une donnée = une valeur)

---

- Est-ce que c'est **correct** ? Est-ce qu'il y au moins une décision ou est-ce qu'il y a un flou ?
- Si oui (ou si ça a du sens pour vous), quand utiliser **le singulier plutôt que le pluriel** ?

Answer (score 2):

Oui c'est tout à fait correct.

On peut effectivement voir *une donnée* comme *une valeur*

Pour ce qui est de l'utilisation, c'est la même que pour tous les autres mots, s'il n'y en a qu'un *une donnée*, sinon *des données*

Il peut y avoir certains cas où le pluriel est moins évident comme après la complétion d'un formulaire par exemple, ou des données personnelles.

> Vos données ont bien été enregistrées

Car en général dans un formulaires il y a plusieurs champs (nom, prénom, âge, ...), chacun étant considéré comme une donnée, mais la réponse du formulaire, elle, est unique.

Quelques phrases d'exemple.

> La dernière donnée saisie n'est pas correcte, veuillez la corriger
>
> Si l'on prend au hasard une donnée, parmi toutes celles enregistrées, il y a de fortes chances que cela soit un O.
>
> Les données suivantes ont bien été mises à jour : âge, nom.